# Работа с маршрутизатором

Tags: php, router

В курсе Php Start показан пример роутера. Как сделать так чтобы при вводе в адресную строку несуществующий в маршрутах uri ничего не происходило, или хотя бы просто происходило перенаправление?

```
class Router
{

    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $routesPath = ROOT . '/config/routes.php';
        $this->routes = include($routesPath);
    }


    /*
     * Return request string
     * */
    private function getUri()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        }
    }


    public function run()
    {

        // get request string
        $uri = $this->getUri();

        // Check for request to routes (routes.php)
        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {

            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {

                // Get the internal path of the external rule
                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);


                // Define controller and action is handling the request
                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                $controllerName = array_shift($segments) . 'Controller';
                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                $actionName = 'action' . ucfirst(array_shift($segments));

                $parameters = $segments;

                // Connection file class controller

                $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' . $controllerName . '.php';

                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {

                    include_once($controllerFile);
                }

                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;

                $res = call_user_func_array([$controllerObject, $actionName], $parameters);

                if ($res != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит `в маршрутах uri ничего не происходило`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был невнимателен из-за отсутствия навыков. Добавил в код вот это и теперь при вводе непрописанной в маршрутах uri скрип делает редирект в корень сайта.

```
...
$res = call_user_func_array([$controllerObject, $actionName], $parameters);

                if ($res != null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    header("Location: /");
                }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, вам нужно что-то делать если `$this->getUri();` нет в `$this->routes`. Можно создать логическую переменную и если адрес совпал хоть с одним маршрутом, присваивать ей значение, а после цикла проверять значение этой переменной.

```
$route_found = false;
foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {
   if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {
      $route_found = true;
      /*Остальной код*/
   }
}
if(!$route_found){
   /*Делайте то, что нужно*/
}
```

Comment: Наверно... Нравится ход ваших мыслей. Но как это реализовать? Примерчик бы, я совершенный нуб.

Comment: @phpХ обновил ответ.